reusing duckdb connection in windows with `DBI::dbSendQuery()`
Calling the following function twice will throw an error in Windows, but not Ubuntu.  I tried on two machines each.  It is related to DBI::dbSendQuery() -if that's commented out, the function can execute repeatedly without error.  All four machines have duckdb v1.0.0 and DBI v1.2.3.  This happens (with similar error messages) if the arguments are inside or outside the call to duckdb::duckdb().
The only solution I've found it to keep the connection opened the whole execution.  It requires restarting R (ie, ctl+shift+F10 in RStudio) to be able to hit the same DuckDB file again.
What can I do differently?
path_db <- "~/so-question.duckdb"
f <- function() {
  sql_1 <-
    "
      DROP TABLE if exists t1;
      CREATE TABLE t1 (
        id   int  primary key,
        s    text not null,
      );
    "
  sql_2 <- "SHOW ALL TABLES;"
  cn <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = path_db, bigint = "integer64")
  # Alternative connection
  # cn <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(dbdir = path_db, bigint = "integer64"))
  
  ds_1 <- DBI::dbSendQuery(cn, sql_1)
  ds_2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(cn, sql_2)
  DBI::dbDisconnect(cn, shutdown = TRUE)
  rm(cn)
  
  ds_2
}

f()
#      database schema name column_names     column_types temporary
# 1 so-question   main   t1        id, s INTEGER, VARCHAR     FALSE

f() # Throws an error in Windows, but not Ubutu.

output:
Error: rapi_startup: Failed to open database: {"exception_type":"IO","exception_message":"File is already open in \nC:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\rsession-utf8.exe (PID 14948)"}

output from alternate connection:
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'drv' in selecting a method for function 'dbConnect': rapi_startup: Failed to open database: {"exception_type":"IO","exception_message":"File is already open in \nC:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\resources\\app\\bin\\rsession-utf8.exe (PID 12140)"}


What happens if you gc() between the two invocations?

@krlmlr, it works on all four machines now.  If you make it answer, I'd love to accept it and add to your 25k.

@krlmlr, I was hoping to put gc() inside f(), so the caller wouldn't be responsible for lower-level calls.  But it throws the same error if it's inside.  Any ideas how to avoid placing that responsibility on the user?

There could be a backward pointer from ds_1 that is only removed after f() is exiting. If that fails, this could be a new question with a separate reprex.

That's awesome.  Yes, changing ds_1 <- DBI::dbSendQuery(cn, sql_1) to just DBI::dbSendQuery(cn, sql_1) works.

Why do you need dbSendQuery() anyway? It's a no-op in this case, just costly.

Got you, table creation. dbExecute() is better than dbSendQuery() here.

I see the benefits of dbExecute(), and I'm guessing its call to dbClearResult() helps release some lock?  As a result, gc() isn't needed anymore, right?  At least it doesn't on my machines.

Yeah, dbSendQuery() returns a result object, dbExecute() already clears it.

Recent versions of the duckdb R package disconnect properly, but garbage collection must be invoked.
path_db <- "~/so-question.duckdb"
f <- function() {
  sql_1 <-
    "
      DROP TABLE if exists t1;
      CREATE TABLE t1 (
        id   int  primary key,
        s    text not null,
      );
    "
  sql_2 <- "SHOW ALL TABLES;"
  cn <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = path_db, bigint = "integer64")
  # Alternative connection
  # cn <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(dbdir = path_db, bigint = "integer64"))
  
  # Use dbExecute() for side effects
  DBI::dbExecute(cn, sql_1)
  ds_2 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(cn, sql_2)
  
  # No longer need shutdown = TRUE
  DBI::dbDisconnect(cn)
  rm(cn)
  
  # This is needed
  gc()
  
  ds_2
}

